# Plone/Python Create User Account

Tags: python, plone, user-accounts

I have a Plone instance (4.2.2) running and need to automate the creation of user accounts.  I'd really like to do this using an external Python script or some other Linux-based command line utility (such as "curl").

If I use curl, I can authenticate to gain access to the "@@new_user" page, but I can't seem to get the right POST setup in the headers.

If I don't use curl and use a Python script instead, are there any utilities or libraries that can do this?  I've tried using libraries such as `Products.CMFCore.utils.getToolByName` and getting the "portal_registration" - but I can't seem to get that to work in a regular script (one that has no request/context).

This script needs to run once every N minutes on the server (where the user information is grabbed from an external database).  I also need there to be no password - and select the option to email the user to set their own password, and I need to add this user to a pre-defined group.

Are there any suggestions - perhaps another utility or built-in library that would better suite these requirements?

Comment: You cannot use the external database as a user source directly?

Comment: Right now we let Plone handle all of the user account information internally - on our external database, we have a table setup with a minimal list of credentials (full name, username, and email) that we want to create Plone accounts from.

Comment: You can create a Plone user source that can query those directly, but store passwords in Plone (once generated). Is that an option at all?

Comment: That does sound promising - however we already have hundreds of accounts in Plone's internal database.  If those aren't affected (and if the difference is transparent) then I'd be willing to give it a shot.  I assume there's documentation for this?

Comment: See http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/users-and-security/pluggable-authentication-service/referencemanual-all-pages; you'll have to migrate your existing users, but that's entirely doable from a python migration script reading the current users source.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As of now, that link doesn't work anymore. You don't by chance know a current address -  or, even better: a general rule to translate those old URLs to `docs.plone.org` addresses?

Comment: @Tobias: sorry, I don't know. http://docs.plone.org/4/en/old-reference-manuals/pluggable_authentication_service/ perhaps? Or http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/sessions/login.html? It's been too long for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are many scripts floating around for batch imports of users. A good one is Tom Lazar's CSV import http://plone.org/documentation/kb/batch-adding-users . Tom's script could be very easily adapted to run as a Zope "run" script if you need to run it from the command line, say as a cron job. "Run" scripts are scripts processed via command like "bin/client5 run my_script.py" using a Zope or ZEO client instance.

However, a strategy like this is one-way. It sound's from the conversation you had with Martijn like you might be better off by creating a Pluggable Authentication System (PAS) plugin to provide a connection to your external database source. The great thing about this strategy is that you can very precisely determine which user properties have which source (external DB or Plone membership properties manager). Docs (as MJ indicated) are at http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/users-and-security/pluggable-authentication-service/referencemanual-all-pages .

Make sure to look and see if there is already a plugin written for your external data source. There are already plugins for many auth schemes and dbs (like LDAP and SQLAlchemy).